# How can I assign unique and linear key for each object within an array that's in an object within another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, map-function

The dataset that I'm working with is structured like this:

[image]

After running my code, I'm getting this result:

[image]

But I need the objects' keys in the "Dessert" to be 3, 4, 5 instead of relooping from 0 after the first iteration.

My current code looks like this (sorry for the indentation- it's acting weird):

```js
const groupSource = [
  {
    title: 'Fruits',
    group: [
      {text: 'apple'},
      {text: 'banana'},
      {text: 'grapefruit'}
    ],

  },
  {
    title: 'Desserts',
    group: [
      {text: 'icecream', color: 'orange'},
      {text: 'chocolate'},
      {text: 'chips'}
    ],
  }
];
class ResultCategory extends React.Component{
   render(){
      return(
        <div>
     {this.props.text}          
        </div>
      );
   }
}
class Result extends React.Component{
   render(){
      return(
        <table>
         <tbody>
      <tr><td>Name:</td><td> {this.props.text} </td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key:</td><td> {this.props.keyz} </td></tr>          </tbody>
        </table>
      );
   }
}
class Search extends React.Component{
   render(){
      var database = this.props.database;
      var ResultsDisplay = database.map((object, index) => {
         return(
            <div>
               <div className="Category">
                  <ResultCategory
                     text={object.title}
                  />
               </div>
               {object.group.map((item, index)=>{
                  return(
                     <li className="results" onClick={this.onClick}>
                        <Result
                           text={item.text}
                           keyz={index}
                        />
                     </li>
                  );
               })}
            </div>
         );
      });
      return(
         <div>
            {ResultsDisplay}
         </div>
      );
   }
}
ReactDOM.render(
     <Search database={groupSource} />,
     document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
*{
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
  
}

li{
  list-style: none;
}
.Category{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try flattening each `{text: <name>}` object to include its group title prop. or in react just use `key={obj.title + i}` so you get `Fruits1`, `Fruits2`, etc

Answer (score 0):

The container component (Search) can track the index counting you want.

```js
const groupSource = [
  {
    title: 'Fruits',
    group: [
      {text: 'apple'},
      {text: 'banana'},
      {text: 'grapefruit'}
    ],

  },
  {
    title: 'Desserts',
    group: [
      {text: 'icecream', color: 'orange'},
      {text: 'chocolate'},
      {text: 'chips'}
    ],
  }
];
class ResultCategory extends React.Component{
   render(){
      return(
        <div>
     {this.props.text}          
        </div>
      );
   }
}
class Result extends React.Component{
   render(){
      return(
        <table>
         <tbody>
      <tr><td>Name:</td><td> {this.props.text} </td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key:</td><td> {this.props.keyz} </td></tr>          </tbody>
        </table>
      );
   }
}
class Search extends React.Component{
   render(){
      var database = this.props.database;
      var totalIndex = 0;
      var ResultsDisplay = database.map((object, index) => {
         return(
            <div>
               <div className="Category">
                  <ResultCategory
                     text={object.title}
                  />
               </div>
               {object.group.map((item, index)=>{
                  return(
                     <li className="results" onClick={this.onClick}>
                        <Result
                           text={item.text}
                           keyz={totalIndex++}
                        />
                     </li>
                  );
               })}
            </div>
         );
      });
      return(
         <div>
            {ResultsDisplay}
         </div>
      );
   }
}
ReactDOM.render(
     <Search database={groupSource} />,
     document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
*{
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
  
}

li{
  list-style: none;
}
.Category{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great :)